# How to insert a Grid with some columns inside an admin form?

Tags: adminhtml, grid, forms, adminform

I need to insert a grid inside the admin form having two columns and each row should be having a delete button. Is there a way to achieve this [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a couple of things. First of all next to the normal `table` you'll have created for your module that stores the data of the `adminhtml` form you need a second `table` that stores the URLs data with the fields

1. entity_id
2. parent_id
3. label
4. url
5. sortorder

Create the resource models accordingly.

**Rendering in the Adminhtml**

Adding a new renderer to the form generator. I've just added the field that will have the renderer

`app/code/[codepool]/Namespace/Module/BLock/Adminhtml/[Module]/Edit/Tab/General.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Module]_Edit_Tab_General extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('[module]_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('[namespace]_[module]')->__('General')));

        [...]       

        $urlsField = $fieldset->addField('urls', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'urls',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('[namespace]_[module]')->__('URLS'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));

    $urlsField = $form->getElement('urls');

    $urlsField->setRenderer(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[namespace]_[module]/adminhtml_[module]_edit_renderer_urls')
    );

    [...]
    }
}
```

The renderer class that adds the phtml template

`app/code/[codepool]/Namespace/Module/BLock/Adminhtml/[Module]/Edit/Renderer/Urls.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Module]_Edit_Renderer_Urls
 extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
 implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface
{

    /**
     * Initialize block
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('[namespace]_[module]/urls.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Render HTML
     *
     * @param Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $this->setElement($element);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }

}
```

And the template that renders the filled in options and adds a javascript template for the other rows.

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/[namespace]_[module]/urls.phtml`

```
$_htmlId      = $this->getElement()->getHtmlId();
$_htmlClass   = $this->getElement()->getClass();
$_htmlName    = $this->getElement()->getName();
$_readonly    = $this->getElement()->getReadonly();

$collection = Mage::registry('[namespace]_[module]_data')->getUrls(); // this gets the URLs from the model that is loaded for this item, so the class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_[Object] needs a method `getUrls`

$_counter = 0;
?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->getElement()->getLabel() ?></td>
    <td colspan="10" class="grid hours">
        <table id="attribute-options-table" class="data border [module]-urls" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>
            <tr class="headings">
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Label') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Url') ?></th>
                <th class="last"><button id="add_new_option_button" title="Add Option" type="button" class="scalable add"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add Option') ?></span></span></span></button></th>
            </tr>
<?php foreach ($collection as $_item): ?>
<tr class="option-row [module]-urls-row" id="urls-row-<?php echo $_counter?>">
    <td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>][label]" value="<?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>][url]" value="<?php echo $_item->getUrl() ?>" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
    <td class="a-left" id="delete_button_container_option_<?php echo $_counter ?>'">
        <input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" type="hidden">
        <input id="delete-row-<?php echo $_counter ?>" type="hidden" class="delete-flag" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[delete][option_<?php echo $_counter ?>]" value=""/>
        <button onclick="$('hour-row-<?php echo $_counter ?>').style.display='none'; $('delete-row-<?php echo $_counter ?>').setValue(1);" title="Delete" type="button" class="scalable delete delete-option"><span><span><span>Delete</span></span></span></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
        $_counter++;
    endforeach;
?>
</tbody></table>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

var _form_html_row = '<tr class="option-row [module]-urls-row" id="urls-row-{{id}}"><td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_{{id}}][label]" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td><td><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_{{id}}][url]" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td><td class="a-left" id="delete_button_container_option_{{id}}"><input name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[value][option_{{id}}][id]" value="" type="hidden"><input id="delete-row-{{id}}" type="hidden" class="delete-flag" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[delete][option_{{id}}]" value=""/><button onclick="$(\'urls-row-{{id}}\').style.display=\'none\'; $(\'delete-row-{{id}}\').setValue(1);" title="Delete" type="button" class="scalable delete delete-option"><span><span><span>Delete</span></span></span></button></td></tr>';

var _urls_counter = <?php echo $_counter?>;

$('add_new_option_button').observe('click', function(){
    $('attribute-options-table').insert(_form_html_row.replace(/\{\{id\}\}/ig, _urls_counter));
    _urls_counter++;
});

//]]></script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Storing the data on save**

`app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/controllers/Adminhtml/[Module]Controller.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Adminhtml_[Module]Controller 
 extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) 
        {
            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

                // Save the data
                $model = Mage::getModel('[namespace]_[module]/object');

                $urls = $postData['urls'];
                unset($postData['urls']);
                $model->setData($postData);

                $model->save();


                $parentId = $model->getId();

                // save urls
                if (!empty($urls))
                {
                    foreach ($urls['delete'] as $_key => $_row)
                    {
                        $delete = (int)$_row;
                        $urlsData = $urls['value'][$_key];

                        $_urls = Mage::getModel('[namespace]_[module]/[urls]')->load((int)$urlsData['id']); // this is the model that stores the URLs data in a second table

                        if ($delete && 0 < (int)$_urls->getId()) // exists & required to delete
                        {
                            $_urls->delete();
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (!$delete)
                        {
                            if (0 == (int)$_urls->getId()) // new item
                            {
                                Mage::getModel('[namespace]_[module]/[urls]')->setData(array(
                                    'parent_id' => $parentId,
                                    'label' => $urlsData['label'],
                                    'url'   => $urlsData['url'],
                                    'sortorder' => $urlsData['sortorder'],
                                ))->save();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $_urls->addData(array(
                                    'store_id'  => $parentId,
                                    'label' => $urlsData['label'],
                                    'url'   => $urlsData['url'],
                                    'sortorder' => $urlsData['sortorder'],
                                ))->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // And wrap up the transaction
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                [...]

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                [...]
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

}
```

Now earlier I've referenced to the method `getUrls` in the objects model. It would look something like this.

`app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/[Object].php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_[Object] extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    public function getOpeningHours()
    {
        return Mage::getModel('[namespace]_[module]/urls')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $this->getId());
    }
}
```

And that's it!

Comment: Do we need to do anything on the layout file in adminhtml?

Comment: the layout XML can just be the usual one you need

Comment: Still not getting the output rendered by urls.phtml

Comment: did you check if the block classes are loaded, if it can find the phtml file etc? Please try to pinpoint the issue

Comment: It is not able to find the phtml file I think . I am just a beginner in Magento. Maybe that's why I don't know how to bring it.

Comment: let's say you put a `die('Hello!');` just before the line `$this->setTemplate('[namespace]_[module]/urls.phtml');` what happens?

Comment: I am not able to put it inside setRenderer....Dreamweaver is showing an error
$urlsField->setRenderer(
    
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('hm_faq/adminhtml_faq_edit_renderer_urls')
    );

Comment: but does it reach the setTemplate in the `[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Module]_Edit_Renderer_Urls` class?

Comment: No it does not.....I put the die('Hello'); before $this->setTemplate('[namespace]_[module]/urls.phtml'); , Nothing happens

Comment: It is showing 'Hello' now.....which means it is going inside setTemplate. But it is not showing the contents of urls.phtml file

Comment: hmm. can you update your question with the part of your `config.xml` where you define the block namespace? (global > blocks)

Comment: are you sure your adminhtml phtml file is in the right place?

Comment: yes inside app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/[Namespace_Module]/

Comment: it should all be lowercase characters

Comment: yes it is in lowercase characters

Comment: <blocks>
   <hm_faq>
    <class>HM_Faq_Block</class>
   </hm_faq>
  </blocks>

This is what is inside global

Comment: Honestly I'm out of ideas what it could be. this code comes from a module I've built before that works

Comment: Guess I will have to figure it out on my own....Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: I got it. It was my mistake. Your answer worked when I commented the line $collection = Mage::registry('namespace_module_data')->getUrls(); in the urls.phtml file. Maybe because I did not create any resource Model files. I don't know exactly. Can you tell me why this happened?

Comment: Might have been an error that isn't printed :) glad you could solve it

Comment: WHat does second table mean over here?

 $_urls = Mage::getModel('[namespace]_[module]/[urls]')->load((int)$urlsData['id']); // this is the model that stores the URLs data in a second table


How is this different from

 // Save the data
                $model = Mage::getModel('[namespace]_[module]/object');


What is the difference between /object and /[url] over here?

Comment: Ok there is a new issue....I am not able to delete the rows after saving them....should I write a separate function for that?

Answer (score 7):

It's easier than that. I have described it in full at http://www.integer-net.com/2015/03/17/how-to-create-tables-in-magento-system-configuration/. In short:

system.xml:

```
<shipping_costs translate="label">
    <label>Shipping Cost based on Price</label>
    <frontend_model>namespace_module/config_shippingCosts</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</shipping_costs>
```

As you can see, the code only adds a frontend model and a backend model to the usual definition of new fields.

The backend model is used to modify saving the field value to and loading from the database. Always use adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array here.
The frontend model is in fact a block, despite its name. It is used to render the table with the defined columns. The frontend models always inherits from the class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract.

In my example the frontend model class looks like this:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Config_ShippingCosts 
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract
{
    public function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('from_price', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('From Price'),
            'style' => 'width:100px',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('cost', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Shipping Cost'),
            'style' => 'width:100px',
        ));

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Add');
    }
}
```

Nothing more is needed to display a table with two columns of 100px each.

If you want to use the values from the configuration somewhere, you just have to unserialize the field data:

```
$shippingCosts = Mage::getStoreConfig('namespace_module/general/shipping_costs');
if ($shippingCosts) {
    $shippingCosts = unserialize($shippingCosts);
    if (is_array($shippingCosts)) {
        foreach($shippingCosts as $shippingCostsRow) {
            $fromPrice = $shippingCostsRow['from_price'];
            $cost = $shippingCostsRow['cost'];
            ...
        }
    } else {
        // handle unserializing errors here
    }
}
```